# When is operation complexity such that dplyr rowwise is needed?

Tags: r, dplyr

According to the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/rowwise) the dplyr `rowwise` operator can be used to "support arbitrary complex operations that need to be applied to each row".  I find this a little vague.  For example, addition does not appear to rise to the level of complexity required for a rowwise:

```
df <- data.frame( a =  c(1,2,3,4), b = c(5,6,7,8)) 
df %>% 
  mutate(
    c = a+b,
  )

  a b  c
1 1 5  6
2 2 6  8
3 3 7 10
4 4 8 12
```

But a very similar function, `sum` does.  For example:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    d = sum(a,b)
  ) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    e = sum(a,b)
  )

  a b  d  e
1 1 5 36  6
2 2 6 36  8
3 3 7 36 10
4 4 8 36 12
```

My question is, when exactly do we need to use `rowwise` in the course of dplyr operations? Anytime the operation is not a basic arithmetic one or are there some other rules for when an operation will be automatically treat its inputs as rowwise vs column wise?

Comment: Often I find that `rowwise() %>% mutate(...)` can be replaced with a call to `mutate(a = Map(...))` (or `mapply` or `purrr::pmap` or one of its siblings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer is that `sum`, `max` is not "vectorised", it acceps multiple vectors and gives you the aggregated answer, a bit weird. I usually try to use functions that dont require `rowwise` since it is slow, and the risk of error is high. An solution to your simple case could be:

```
library(hablar)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame( a =  c(1,2,3,4), b = c(5,6,7,8)) 

df %>% mutate(c = row_sum(a:b))
```